# PostgreSql: why this update works incorrectly?

Tags: postgresql

There is table t1 in what I need to replace id with new value.

The 2nd table t_changes contains substitutions
old_id->new_id.
But when I do UPDATE the t1 contains the same new id value for all records. 
What is incorrect?
The same update works in T-SQL successfully.

```
drop table t1;
drop table t2;
drop table t_changes;

create table t1
(id INT,name text, new_id INT default(0));

create table t_changes
(old_id INT,new_id int)

insert into t1(id,NAME)
VALUES (1,'n1'),(2,'n2'),(3,'n3');

insert into t_changes(old_id,new_id)
values(1,11),(2,12),(3,13),(4,13)

select * from t1;
select * from t_changes;

-------!!!!
update t1
set new_id = n.new_id
from t1 t 
inner join t_changes n
on n.old_id=t.id;

select * from t1
------------------------------
"id"    "name"  "new_id"
-----------------
"1" "n1"    "11"
"2" "n2"    "11"
"3" "n3"    "11"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your Postgres `update` statement:

```
update t1
    set new_id = n.new_id
    from t1 t inner join
         t_changes n
         on n.old_id = t.id;
```

The problem is that the `t1` in the `update` refers to a different `t1` in the `from`.  You intend for them to be the same reference.  You can do this as:

```
update t1
    set new_id = n.new_id
    from t_changes n
    where n.old_id = t.id;
```

Your syntax is fairly close to the syntax supported by some other databases (such as SQL Server).  However, for them, you would need to use the *table alias* in the update:

```
update t
    set new_id = n.new_id
    from t1 t inner join
         t_changes n
         on n.old_id = t.id;
```

Comment: Ok, thnx. You are right. I am porting SQL Server business logic to PostgreSql and that is the reason of problem like that. This statement works in T-Sql, but does not work as expected in PostgreSql. I need to review all update stmts like this one.

Comment: @Oleg: this is documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html#AEN88864): "*Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*"

Comment: @Oleg . . . Your query would not have worked correctly in SQL Server either, because the `t1` is given the alias of `t` in the `FROM` clause.  The `UPDATE` is using the table name instead of the alias (although perhaps your actual query doesn't have this problem).

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this instead:

```
update t1
set new_id = (SELECT new_id FROM t_changes WHERE old_id=id);
```

Note that if for some row in `t1` there is no corresponding row in `t_changes`, this will change `t1.new_id` to `NULL`.